# Spring: ResourceResolver not called from error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application that adds a resource handler for static resources (mainly CSS and JS files) using the `addResourceHandlers` method of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. This resource handler is further configured to enable a `VersionResourceResolver` Basically this is

```
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ResourceHandlerRegistration registration = registry.addResourceHandler(...)
        ResourceChainRegistration chainRegistration = registration.resourceChain(...);
        chainRegistration.addResolver(
            new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy(...));
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, when the user sees an error page (for example the 404 page), this `VersionResourceResolver` won't be used. (The error pages are configured using `@ExceptionHandler`s in a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class.) The error pages will be rendered and displayed fine, however, the resources loaded on this page don't have version applied.

The Spring Boot documentation has a note saying that an `ERROR` dispatcher needs special treatment, however, I cannot figure out how to apply this advice in the context of our `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a my opensource project and I resolve in this way.

I create an @Controller class like this:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/exception")
    public String exception(Model model,Exception ex,Locale locale,HttpServletRequest httpRequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse){

        ex.printStackTrace();

        model.addAttribute("templatePath", "exception/exception");
        model.addAttribute("template", "content");
        try{
            model.addAttribute("exceptionMessage",messageSource.getMessage(String.format("exception.body.%s",httpResponse.getStatus()),new Object[]{},locale));
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e){
            model.addAttribute("exceptionMessage",messageSource.getMessage("exception.body",new Object[]{},locale));
        }
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and then I customize the servlet container configuration in this way:

```
  @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer exceptionHandling() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/exception"));
    }
```

in feew words I make a special page for error /exception in this case and then configure the embedded tomcat for use this url in case of exceptions

In the Autoconfiguration classes of Spring boot you can see in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController this documentation:

```
Basic global error {@link Controller}, rendering {@link ErrorAttributes}. More specific
 * errors can be handled either using Spring MVC abstractions (e.g.
 * {@code @ExceptionHandler}) or by adding servlet
 * {@link AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactory#setErrorPages container error pages}
```

I hope that tis can help you

Comment: the compleate code you can see at the link https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary/tree/master/user-documentlibrary-client

Comment: I use thymeleaf as template engine

Comment: Hi Valerio, thanks for your response. I edited my question to make my specific problem clear. It's not that the error pages as such are not working. The problem is that a registered ResourceResolver does not work on error pages. I have debugged it a little bit and the resolver simply is not called for static resources on an error page.

Comment: i'm sorry I don't understand well the question....  i'm not free now we had problem in a production enviroments but as soon as i'm free i try to answare you

Comment: well I see bether the offical documentation and personaly I don't understand well how you hve done. In other words if read at the link

Comment: can you give more details on your configuration? I had read again the documentation and could be better for me in order to understand better the problem, having the your enviroments and configurations,

Comment: however consider taht the configuration class that govern the ErrorController is ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration and is loaded bore any WebMvcAutoConfiguration including the yourself configuration class.